# using zip command to get the last element of all the lists from list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists:

```
       Y= [[192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200],
         [507, 508, 509],
         [526, 527, 528, 529],
         [560, 561],
         [635, 636, 637]]
```

and I want the last and first elements of each list into a separate list. 
I used the zip command:

```
list(zip(*Y))[0]
```

for all first elements and gave me:

```
[192,507,526,560,635]
```

but when I use `list(zip(*Y))[-1]`

I got `[193, 508, 527, 561, 636]`

instead of `[200,509,529,561,637]`

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: zip is a zip-to-smallest-list function, what's wrong with `[x[-1] for x in Y]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close - just use the reversed list iterators:

```
>>> list(zip(*[reversed(y) for y in Y]))[0]
(200, 509, 529, 561, 637)
```

Or, more directly, a list comprehension:

```
[y[-1] for y in Y]
```

Answer (score 2):

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) zips up iterables of the same length. If you give it iterables of *different* lengths, it stops at the end of the first one.

So, since your shortest list is length 2, you get the first elements, then the second elements… and that's it, so `[-1]` returns the second elements.

You could use `itertools.zip_longest`, but that won't really help, because it handles iterables of different lengths by filling in extra `None` values at the end, not by… inserting extra values in the middle or something that would stretch them all out to the same length.

---

The easiest thing to do is to take the first and last of each *first*, before zipping:

```
Y= [[192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200],
    [507, 508, 509],
    [526, 527, 528, 529],
    [560, 561],
    [635, 636, 637]]

FL = [(sublist[0], sublist[-1]) for sublist in Y]
```

Then you can transpose that with `zip`:

```
F, L = zip(*FL)
```

---

Or just not `zip` anything, since you're not getting any real benefit out of transposing things anyway, just making things more complicated:

```
F = [sublist[0] for sublist in Y]
L = [sublist[-1] for sublist in Y]
```

---

Alternatively, you could zip the forward and backward lists:

```
F = zip(*Y)
L = zip(*map(reversed, Y))
```

And then get the first elements out of each of those:

```
f, l = next(F), next(L) # or list(F)[0] if you insist
```

I think this is the closest to what you were trying to do, but it seems like the most complicated way to do it.